# Question about compact operator in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I am reading Compact operator in a Hilbert space which is defined as 
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ be a bounded operator, we say $T$ is a compact operator if for any bounded sequence $x_n$ in $H$, The image $A(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.
I want to construct an example for a non-compact operator in $l^2$ for that I am thinking to define an identity map in $l^2$ but I am not getting which sequence to define in $l^2$ so that it is convergent but it has no convergent subsequence. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm assuming $A$ should be $T$ in your post.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Id}:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ is not compact operator as $\text{Id}({\overline{B(0, 1)}}) =\overline{B(0, 1)}$ is not compact.

A norm space is finite dimensional iff closed unit ball is compact. $\ell^2$ is not finite dimensional.

---

More specifically, choose $(e_n) _{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ where $e_n=(0, 0,\ldots, 1,0,\ldots) $ i.e $1$ in the $n$- th place and zeros everywhere.

Then $\|e_n\|_2=1 \space \forall  n$ implies $(e_n) $ is a bounded sequence in $\ell^2$ space but
This sequence doesn't have any convergent subsequence.

---

> I am not getting which sequence to define in $ l_2 $ so that it is
> convergent but it has no convergent subsequence.

This is impossible as every subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent.

Comment: if I define a sequence $x_n$ in $l^2$ and a Operator $T \colon l^2 \to l^2$ such that $T(x_n)$=$n^2x_n$ where $x_n$=$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$,is it correct example ?